# How to make the length of the field

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote the below SQL query to make the fiel length 40,

But I am receiving an error

```
to_char('IST'||' '||to_char(to_date(sysdate), 'mmyyyy'),40) des
```

Comment: You shouldn't apply to_date function on sysdate. It already of date datatype.

Answer (score -2):

Use RPAD-function:

`RPAD('IST'||' '||to_char(to_date(sysdate), 'mmyyyy'),40)`